# Add values to multiple datagridview columns and add all records to another datagridview

Tags: c#, list, object, button, datagridview

Hi this is my requirements
I have a datagridview showing student details each row. Each row is a student object.

I have four or more than one rows. (means four max or minimum 2 students) in the datagrid view. I want to add these student records a single group id from a text box by clicking a button and to add in to another datagridview .Means each row group id column should be modified with group id given in the text box and all the rows in the datagridview should be added to the second grid.

```
           **//In button click event
           for (int rc = 0; rc < (dgvSorted.Rows.Count);rc++ )
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvSorted.Rows)
                {
                     Student studobj = new Student();
                          studobj.idNumber =  
                   dgvSorted.Rows[row.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    studobj.fName =dgvSorted.Rows[row.Index].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    studobj.lName =dgvSorted.Rows[row.Index].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                    studobj.mailE  dgvSorted.Rows[row.Index].Cells[3].Value.ToString();

                    studobj.grId = txtGrId.Text;
                    lstStudentFNL.Add(studobj);
                    BindingSource binding = new BindingSource();
                    binding.DataSource = lstStudentFNL;
                    dgvFinal.DataSource = binding;
                    dgvSorted.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index);
                }** 
   **List<Student> lstStudentFNL = new List<Student>();**
```

but this will add only a single record it will not add all records in the grid to the second grid assigning the groupid. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Sorry but it's really hard to understand what you want to acheive.

Comment: @wonko79 

assigning four records with one group id and add that four records to another datagridview. Using list and list objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you use databinding for both DataGridViews a working example would look like this:

```
string groupIdFromTextBox = "xyz";

            List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
            students.Add(new Student { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), LastName = "l1", FirstName = "f1", EMail = "e1" });
            students.Add(new Student { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), LastName = "l2", FirstName = "f2", EMail = "e2" });
            students.Add(new Student { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), LastName = "l3", FirstName = "f3", EMail = "e3" });
            students.Add(new Student { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), LastName = "l4", FirstName = "f4", EMail = "e4" });

            BindingSource dgvSortedBindingSource = new BindingSource();
            dgvSortedBindingSource.DataSource = students;

            List<Student> students2 = new List<Student>();
            BindingSource dgvSortedBindingSource2 = new BindingSource();
            dgvSortedBindingSource2.DataSource = students2;

            // This goes to your click event
            foreach (Student s in dgvSortedBindingSource.List)
            {
                s.GroupId = groupIdFromTextBox;
                dgvSortedBindingSource2.Add(s);
            }

            dgvSortedBindingSource.Clear();
            // This goes to your click event
```